# Scala enumeration to int

Tags: scala

Is there a way to identify that a given object is an Enumeration value?

`x.isInstanceOf[Enumeration.$Value]` doesn't seem to work, and from what I understand of path-dependent types, shouldn't.

I'd like to write a function that given any Enumeration value, returns its id. Alternatively, an implicit that converts the Enumeration to Int would also be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x.isInstanceOf[Enumeration#Value]` works for me. From the [specification, Section 3.2.2 "Type Projection"](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf#page=21).

Answer (score 6):

Class scala.Enumeration.Value has a member field 'id' which is the internal integer value. If not specifically specified, it starts from 0.

```
scala> object Weekday extends Enumeration {           
     | val Mon, Tue, Wedn, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
     | }
defined module Weekday

scala> Weekday.Mon.id
res5: Int = 0
```

Comment: You should explain your code- It is in risc for being ranked as "low quality post".

Comment: How do you specify it?